# How to parse empty string to array of byte?

Tags: arrays, delphi, parsing, compatibility

I have to use an old unit that uses ansistring, ansichar et al on Android, previously built on Delphi 2007, so I'm working on making it compatible with XE7.

I've come across several lines that would have put an empty string into an AnsiString, like so: `FAnsiString := ''`, but now that AnsiString is an array of bytes(`FAnsiString : array of Byte`) I get the message E2010 incompatible types.

I've tried to parse it by creating a type for the array (`type TArrayOfByte = array of Byte`) and trying to parse it like so: `FAnsiString := TArrayOfByte ('')`.
But then I get E2089 Invalid TypeCast.

How can I make it work correctly?

An simplification of how it should work is below.
Basically I want a function that returns an array of bytes.
Depending on the arguments, the result of that function should be an empty string.

```
{$ifdef android}
  type AnsiString = array of Byte;
{$endif}

function FooBar(arguments) : AnsiString
begin
  if false then
  Result := '';
end;
```

Comment: It's never been right to cast a string to an array. Normally you would use something like that. `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)` and `GetString` to go in the opposite direction.  I think we need to see more code. Without knowing more, we can only guess. Perhaps `FAnsiString := nil` is all you need. But we cannot see what you do with these arrays.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added a code example. Does that make it clearer what it needs to do?

Comment: Not so much. I have a question for you. What do you want to appear in that array of byte? A single element with value `0`, for a null terminator, or an array of length 0? What's more, how are you planning on making this code work on desktop platforms? I'd guess that your entire approach is wrong, but you've not asked about that. I'd expect that you should work internally with text stored in the native string type, and convert to byte arrays only when you need to. That is at the interop boundary. We cannot see any of that though.

Comment: And continuing the theme, it seems likely that you have other code that casts a string to an array of bytes.  That's wrong.  That will end in tears.  It's time for you to step back and consider your entire approach.

Comment: Think of this type AnsiString = array of Byte as  type AnsiString = array of AnsiChar;  You can't set an empty string value to it...doesn't make since.

Comment: An `array of byte` with no content? `Result := [];`

Comment: @Sir Rufo that won't compile on the desktop though. Asker's problems are far deeper than making an empty array.

Comment: `[]` is not valid syntax for a dynamic array. The correct way to return an empty array is `Result := nil` or `SetLength(Result, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi strings and dynamic arrays both contain a `nil` pointer when they are empty.  So this:

```
var
  FAnsiString: AnsiString;

FAnsiString := '';
```

Is effectively doing this behind the scenes:

```
// FAnsiString := '';
if Pointer(FAnsiString) <> nil then
begin
  // decrement reference count, if 0 then free memory ...
  Pointer(FAnsiString) := nil;
end;
```

Dynamic arrays do the exact same thing.  This:

```
var
  FAnsiString: array of Byte;

FAnsiString := nil;
// Alternatively:
// SetLength(FAnsiString, 0);
```

Is effectively doing the same thing as the `AnsiString` cleanup behind the scenes:

```
// FAnsiString := nil;
if Pointer(FAnsiString) <> nil then
begin
  // decrement reference count, if 0 then free memory ...
  Pointer(FAnsiString) := nil;
end;
```

Both `AnsiString` and dynamic arrays are compiler-managed ref-counted types.  They are both auto-initialized to `nil`.

Likewise, `AnsiString` comparisons for empty strings:

```
var
  FAnsiString: AnsiString;

if FAnsiString = '' then
...
if FAnsiString <> '' then
```

Are effectively just checking for a `nil` pointer:

```
if Pointer(FAnsiString) = nil then
...
if Pointer(FAnsiString) <> nil then
```

Same with dynamic arrays, only you can do it without a typecast:

```
var
  FAnsiString: array of byte;

if FAnsiString = nil then
...
if FAnsiString <> nil then
```

The alternative is to use `Length()` and `SetLength()`, which works for both strings and dynamic arrays:

```
var
  FAnsiString: AnsiString;

if Length(FAnsiString) = 0 then
  ...

if Length(FAnsiString) <> 0 then
  ...

SetLength(FAnsiString, 0);
```

```
var
  FAnsiString: array of byte;

if Length(FAnsiString) = 0 then
  ...

if Length(FAnsiString) <> 0 then
  ...

SetLength(FAnsiString, 0);
```

And, of course, there is always Andreas Hausladen's patch to enable `AnsiString` in the mobile compilers:

[The Return of the Byte-Strings](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/10/the-return-of-the-byte-strings/)

[System.ByteStrings support for XE5 Update 2](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2013/12/system-bytestrings-support-for-xe5-update-2/) (and XE6 and XE7)

Comment: The XE7 download can be found on the same page as the XE5 one. That patch is an even better solution than trying to replace everything myself.

Comment: Odd that there was originally an XE7-specific blog post, and then it was taken down and the links moved to the XE5 blog post. Oh well.

Comment: @Friso Wouldn't it be better to stop using ANSI?

Comment: It would be, but it's from old system and I need to keep it backwards compatible.

Comment: There is a big difference between loading/saving legacy data at runtime, and compiling code in a legacy compiler. Different kinds of backwards compatibility.  Processing legacy data in modern compilers does not *require* the use of `AnsiString`.  So this exercise is really about supporting legacy compilers. Strive to get rid of that, then this problem goes away.  Otherwise try to abstract the code logic to be compiler neutral.

Comment: @Friso As I've said before, I do think it likely that you are going about this the wrong way. I think you are setting traps for yourself.